# Complex Replacement

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

Use the complex replacement to find a particular solution to the differential equation $$x'' + 2x' + 2x = e^{-t}\cos(2t).$$

I have been able to solve a particular solution for $x'' + 2x' + 2x = \cos(2t)$, which is $\sin(2*t)/5 - \cos(2*t)/10$. For $x'' + 2x' + 2x = e^{-t}$, I got a particular solution of $e^{-t}$ itself. I'm not sure if either (or both) of my particular solutions are wrong, but when I multiplied them together to get my final answer, I was marked wrong. Could someone please help me understand how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't do that multiplying particular solutions

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier, start with $x(t)=e^{-t} z(t)$ to make the equation
$$z''+z=\cos(2t)$$
$$z''+z=0 \implies z=c_1 \sin(t)+c_2 \cos(t)$$ and the particular solution of the complete equation is just $\frac 1 3 \cos(2t)$.

Just go back to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your answers are correct. Your mistake is to multiply them to get the final answer.
If you want to integrate this differential equation
$$x'' + 2x' + 2x = e^{-t}\cos(2t).$$
Then use Claude's trick or use 
$\cos t= \frac {e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$
$$2x'' + 4x' + 4x = e^{-t(2i+1)}+e^{t(2i-1)}.$$

Using complex replacement 
$$z'' + 2z' + 2z = e^{t(2i-1)}$$
$$P(s) =s^2+2s+2 \implies P(2i-1)=-3 $$
$$z_p=\frac {e^{t(2i-1)}}{-3} $$
$$y_p=\Re (z_p)=-\frac 1 3 e^{-t} \cos(2t)$$
Finally,
$$ \implies y=e^{-t}\left(c_1\cos t +c_2 \sin t -\frac 1 3 \cos(2t)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x'' + 2x' + 2x = e^{-t}\cos(2t)$$
$$\implies (D^2+2D+2)x= e^{-t}\cos(2t)\qquad\text{where} \quad D\equiv \dfrac{d}{dt}~.$$

For particular integral (P.I.),

P.I.$~=\dfrac{1}{D^2+2D+2}~e^{-t}\cos(2t)$

$~~~~~~=e^{-t}~\dfrac{1}{(D-1)^2+2(D-1)+2}~\cos(2t)~~~~~~~~$ (using note $1$, option $2$)

$~~~~~~=e^{-t}~\dfrac{1}{D^2+1}~\cos(2t)$

$~~~~~~=e^{-t}~\dfrac{1}{-(2)^2+1}~\cos(2t)~~~~~~~~$  (using note $2$, option $2$)

$~~~~~~=-\dfrac{1}{3}~e^{-t}~\cos(2t)$

---

**Note$~ 1:$**

> For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) there are some general rules
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{D + a} \phi (x) = e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}\phi(x)$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax} \phi(x) = e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x)$
>
> $3.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \sin ax  = $Imaginary part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $4.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \cos ax  = $Real part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $5.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} (\cos ax + i\sin ax)  = \frac{1}{f(D)} x^n e^{iax}=e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$

**Note$~ 2:$**
For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) of trigonometric functions  you have to follow the following rules:

> If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)$ and $\phi(-a^2)\neq 0$, then
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \sin ax$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \cos ax$
>
> **Note:** If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)=D^2+a^2$, then $\phi(-a^2)= 0$.
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \sin ax= x \frac{1}{2D} \sin ax= -\frac{x}{2a} \cos ax$.
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \cos ax=  x \frac{1}{2D} \cos ax= \frac{x}{2a} \sin ax$.
>
> where $\phi'(D^2)\equiv\frac{d}{dD}\phi(D^2)$